# Javascript image properties

Tags: javascript, html, image

I've been pouring over my code over and over again and I just can't see why it's not working correctly...

Can someone enlighten me? What's the issue here? I just don't see it.

The code should allow the user to enter various values into textboxes to change some of the image's features such as border size, color, width, height, image alt text, and image title.

**This is my code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Properties</title>
<script type="text.javascript">
function changeImage() {
    //applies a new border size
    document.getElementById('img').border = document.getElementById('bs').value;
    //applies a new border color
    document.getElementById('img').style.borderColor = document.getElementById('bc').value;
    //applies a new width
    document.getElementById('img').width = document.getElementById('bw').value;
    //applies a new height
    document.getElementById('img').height = document.getElementById('bh').value;
    //applies a new alt tag
    document.getElementById('img').alt = document.getElementById('ba').value;
    //applies a new title
    document.getElementById('img').title = document.getElementById('bt').value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Change Image Properties</h2>
<img src="KotakuLogo.jpg" id="img" />
<p>
Border Size:<input type="text" id="bs" 
onfocus="this.style.background='#c3c3c3'"
onblur="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'"/><br />
New Border Color:<input type="text" id="bc"
onfocus="this.style.background='#c3c3c3'"
onblur="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'"/><br />
New Border Width:<input type="text" id="bw"
onfocus="this.style.background='#c3c3c3'"
onblur="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'"/><br />
New Border Height:<input type="text" id="bh"
onfocus="this.style.background='#c3c3c3'"
onblur="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'"/><br />
New Border Alt Tag:<input type="text" id="ba"
onfocus="this.style.background='#c3c3c3'"
onblur="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'"/><br />
New Border Title:<input type="text" id="bt"
onfocus="this.style.background='#c3c3c3'"
onblur="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'"/><br />
<input type="button" value="Submit Image Changes" onclick="changeImage()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your script is not interpreted because you put it in the script with wrong type:

```
<script type="text.javascript">...</script>
```

Change it to correct `text/javascript` and it will work. Or even better: remove `type` attribute as redundant, text/javascript is the default type anyway.

And finally, instead of `onfocus="this.style.background='#c3c3c3'" onblur="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'"` use CSS:

```
input:focus {
    background: #c3c3c3;
}
```

Comment: ha ha ha.. you can add this in just a comment.

Comment: @ Ilyas Minmouni, but his reputation is on the line! :P

Comment: be careful about the statement about the units. These are HTML attributes, not CSS properties. HTML attributes don't need a unit

Comment: @VolkerAndres True, didn't notice that width is a property not a style. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for showing me my error.

What's confusing me now though is that when I enter values to change the image, the image disappears. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `document.getElementById` takes a bit of time to run, so you should store its result instead of calling it ten times.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('img');
elem.something = "example";
elem.somethingElse = 1234;
```

`border` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) on an image. You should interact with the style of the element directly instead. The border CSS property covers all styles at once and must be written `SIZEunit style color` such as `5px solid black`.

```
elem.style.border = document.getElementById('bs').value + "px solid " + document.getElementById('bc').value;
```